# Building targets using cmake-ide

Tags: c++, ide, irony-mode

I switched to emacs as my C++ ide. I am using irony mode, company, rtags, and since all of my projects are using cmake, cmake-ide.
I cant realy find something online on how the workflow works with cmake-ide? 
How can I compile targets and run the resulting binarys using cmake-ide? 
Currently I am doing this in terminal mode inside emacs, but I hope I can do this using cmake-ide.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have installed rtags on your machine and set this:

```
(require 'rtags) 
(cmake-ide-setup)
```

then you would just do:

```
M-x cmake-ide-compile
```

That would do the rest for you.

for running the program refer to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593880/compile-and-run-a-c-program-in-emacs

or you can change your CMakeList.txt to run some tests.

Comment: helpful:
http://parbo.github.io/blog/2016/05/10/configuring-emacs-for-cpp/